# Asp.net core Web API for SPA - How to implement Swagger Authentication without having to obtain the Access token outside of the Web API and pass it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui

We are building a SPA with React & ASP.Net core Web API.

React would pass the Auth_Token to ASP.Net core Web API to authenticate, this works.

> As App Registration is done for the `front-end application` along with `Scope & Roles`, I am not sure how to implement Authentication for Swagger in ASP.Net core Web API.

At present, I have the following swagger configuration

```
    private void AddSwagger(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
            {
                Version = "v1",
                Title = "Track Management API",
            });

            var xmlCommentsFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
            var xmlCommentsFullPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlCommentsFile);

            c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlCommentsFullPath);

            var jwtSecurityScheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Scheme = "bearer",
                BearerFormat = "JWT",
                Name = "JWT Authentication",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
                Description = "Put **_ONLY_** your JWT Bearer token on textbox below!",

                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Id = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme
                }
            };

            c.AddSecurityDefinition(jwtSecurityScheme.Reference.Id, jwtSecurityScheme);

            c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
            {
                { jwtSecurityScheme, Array.Empty<string>() }
            });
        });
    }
```

Currently, we must get the Auth_Token outside of the ASP.Net core Web API and pass it to it.

[image]

Can Developers generate the required Auth_Token directly from the Swagger page to simplify this process?

**Update:** The below Swagger configuration try to get the required auth_code however `it uses the Web API URL as the redirection URL` and fails. What I want is that it should use the Front-end URL as the redirection URL to generate the auth_code but pass it to the Web API?

```
            c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Description = "OAuth2.0 Auth Code with PKCE",
                Name = "oauth2",
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
                Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
                {
                    AuthorizationCode = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                    {
                        AuthorizationUrl = new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{this.Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:TenantId")}/oauth2/authorize"),
                        TokenUrl = new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{this.Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:TenantId")}/v2.0/token"),
                        Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                        {
                            { this.Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:ApiScope"), "Allows Read and Write" }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
            {
                {
                    new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                    {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "oauth2" }
                    },
                    new[] { this.Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAd:ApiScope") }
                }
            });
```

The Other option that I see is to add the Web API URL as the redirect URL in the app registration for the lower environment.

Comment: Yes, they can. The actual implementation depends on whether you're using Swashbuckle, NSwag, or some other library. The library you use should have documentation to help you configure authentication.

Comment: If you are using oauth then it is possible to configure directly swagger and do the authentication.

Comment: Use Header name "Authorization" instead of "Auth_Token". You can see an example of authentication with swagger here: https://code-maze.com/swagger-authorization-aspnet-core/

Comment: Please [edit] your title. It is currently just a list of technologies with a question mark after them; neither a real question, nor a "summarization of the problem" as [ask] puts it.

Comment: Can [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72041706/15581227) help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me in combination with Azure AD B2C:

```
config.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
{
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
    Scheme = "oauth2",
    OpenIdConnectUrl = new Uri(builder.Configuration["AzureAd:Authority"]),
    Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
    {
        Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
        {
            AuthorizationUrl = new Uri(builder.Configuration["AzureAd:Authority"], UriKind.Absolute),
            Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { builder.Configuration["AzureAd:Scopes"], "Access web API" },
                }
        }
    }
});

config.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "oauth2" }
            },
            new[] { builder.Configuration["AzureAd:Scopes"] }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your identity provider and add a new allowed redirect Uri to `/swagger/oauth2-redirect.html` example:

```
"RedirectUris": [
   "https://localhost:3379/authentication/login-callback", // for blazor client
   "https://localhost:3379/swagger/oauth2-redirect.html"   // for swagger client
]
```